# ScriptManager and ToolkitScriptManager confusion

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

i am flowwing a tutorial the problem is that When i copy and paste the code.Calendar extender not firing .So i removed script manager and add toolkit scriptmanager and it works .I am wondering what could be the reason  .in case of facing the same problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the Calendar Extender you are currently using is the one provided by AjaxControlToolkit. If this is the case, then the ToolkitScriptManager is what is going to be needed as it is the AjaxControlToolkit version of the ScriptManager and is necessary for you to use all AjaxControlToolkit extensions such as Calendar extender, filtertextbox extender and so on. I hope this helps!

EDIT: As far as I know, ToolScriptManager can handle newer or updated Ajax scripts. This is why when you install AjaxControlToolkit, there are many more extenders than before you installed it. ScriptManager is meant to run Ajax scripts, but it is unable to handle the newer versions of Ajax such as the Calendar Extender, Watermark Extender, and so on properly. If you are using any AjaxControlToolkit extensions, then it is important to use ToolScriptManager has it will handle all the js scripts properly.

Comment: View my edit to see if I made it more clear for you.